# Get items from list if the item contains any of the strings in another list (Python)

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list that looks like:

```
a_list = ['abc','acd','ade','bef','fba','adf','fac']
```

I would like all items in the list if it contains `ab` or `ac`. From the example above, I would like the list to be:

```
b_list = ['abc','acd','fac']
```

I have tried the following, but it gives me a `TypeError`.

```
b_list = [x for x in a_list if any(['ab','ac']) in x]
```

Comment: Unpaired [, need ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there but you can't cross check multiple substrings against a string.  What you can do is use two conditions with an `or`:

```
b_list = [x for x in a_list if 'ab' in x or 'ac' in x]
```

If you have a list of substrings to check, you can use `any()` in your condition but you'll have to iterate over the substrings:

```
subs   = ('ab','ac')
b_list = [x for x in a_list if any(s in x for s in subs)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `any()` has to be a sequence of booleans. You just have a single boolean, and it's not the condition you want.

You want to test whether each of `ab` and `ac` is in the string, not a tuple or list of them.

```
b_list = [string for string in a_list if any(substring in string for substring in ('ab','ac'))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it. You need to iterate over ['ab','ac'] to check if it any of this exists in an item in `a_list`.

```
b_list = [item for item in a_list if any(x in item for x in ['ab','ac'])]
```